# Convert gruntfile config to bash command line browserify call

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, browserify, git-bash

I have this gruntfile.js fragment

```
grunt.initConfig({
    browserify: {
        browser: {
            src: [ require('./package.json').main ],
            dest: './browser/shortid.js'
        },
```

How would I perform exactly the same thing by calling browserify directly (without grunt) from bash command line?  From what directory should I execute browserify?

Comment: I just noticed that you edited your question into what is essentially a very different and separate question. I would not have bothered answering it, had that been in the original question. If you want to ask two questions, do so; don't put two different questions into a single question.

Comment: @cartant - you are right.  I'll try to undo the edit if I can. UPDATE: looks like I was able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command is equivalent and it would need to be executed in the same directory as your `package.json`:

```
browserify . > ./browser/shortid.js
```